# How can I solve this figure size error in a plot?

Tags: python, pandas, image, matplotlib, plot

While I was making some test with plotting I get the same mistake in every plot of the the archive. One of my collegues run the same program I her computer and it works, so I don´t know if I need to import another library or do an upgrade. This is the line that gives me the error:

```
def sub_plot_weekday(df):
    
    fechas = []
    
    for i in range(len(df.index)):
        date = str(df.index[i])[0:7]
        if date not in fechas: 
            fechas.append(date)
    #print(fechas)       
    
    n_subplots = len(fechas)
    n_col = 2
    n_rows = math.ceil(n_subplots/n_col)
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20, 12))
    
    for d in range(len(fechas)):
        #Guardamos en una var el df filtrado x fecha
        filter_df = df[fechas[d]].copy()
        #Guardamos en una lista el nombre de cada día para cada "Fecha" y la ponemos en una columna
        #print(filter_df)
        dates = filter_df.index
        name_m = dates[0].strftime("%B")
        list_weekdays = [dates[i].date().strftime("%A") for i in range(len(dates))]
        filter_df['weekday'] = list_weekdays
        # Creamos un df agrupando por día de semana contando eventos 
        grouped_by_weekday = pd.DataFrame(filter_df[['EVENT', 'weekday']][filter_df['EVENT'] != 0].groupby('weekday').count())
        
        days_index = grouped_by_weekday.index.tolist()
        days_values = grouped_by_weekday.EVENT.tolist()
         
        order_day, order_val = reorder_lists(days_index, days_values)
        #Añadimos subplot 
        plt.subplot(n_rows, n_col, d+1)
        plt.title('Number of Operations per Weekday (' + name_m + ' ' +fechas[d][:4] + ')',fontsize= 17)
        plt.bar(order_day, order_val, color = 'purple') #(0.5,0.1,0.5,0.6) 
        #plt.xticks(order_day, rotation=45)
        for i, val in enumerate(order_val):
            plt.text(i, val, int(val), horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='bottom', fontdict={'fontweight':500, 'size':12})
        plt.ylim(0,26)
        plt.xticks(order_day, rotation=0)
    fig.tight_layout(pad=2.0)
    plt.show()
sub_plot_weekday(dt1)
```

````
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3790, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3789 try:
-> 3790     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3791 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '2019-10'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[11], line 1
----> 1 sub_plot_weekday(dt1)

Cell In[10], line 25, in sub_plot_weekday(df)
     21 #Recoremos cada "fecha" recogida
     23 for d in range(len(fechas)):
     24     #Guardamos en una var el df filtrado x fecha
---> 25     filter_df = df[fechas[d]].copy()
     26     #Guardamos en una lista el nombre de cada día para cada "Fecha" y la ponemos en una columna
     27     #print(filter_df)
     28     dates = filter_df.index

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3896, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3894 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3895     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3896 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3897 if is_integer(indexer):
   3898     indexer = [indexer]

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3797, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3792     if isinstance(casted_key, slice) or (
   3793         isinstance(casted_key, abc.Iterable)
   3794         and any(isinstance(x, slice) for x in casted_key)
   3795     ):
   3796         raise InvalidIndexError(key)
-> 3797     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3798 except TypeError:
   3799     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3800     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3801     #  the TypeError.
   3802     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: '2019-10'
<Figure size 2000x1200 with 0 Axes>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `KeyError: '2019-10'` suggests that '2019-10' is not found in the DataFrame's index. This error occurs in the line `filter_df = df[fechas[d]].copy()`. Here, you're trying to filter the DataFrame `df` by dates stored in the `fechas` list. If your DataFrame index is a DateTimeIndex, and you're trying to access it with string representation of dates, make sure the format matches exactly. If '2019-10' is not present in the index, this could lead to KeyError.

To debug, I recommend printing out your DataFrame's index and the `fechas` list to verify the dates and their formats. Ensure that the dates in `fechas` list are present in the DataFrame's index and the formats match. If the DataFrame index is not a DateTimeIndex, consider converting it to one for easier date-based filtering.

I hope that this helps.

Regards.

Comment: Here is what I have in fechas= ['2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12', '2020-01', '2020-02']
and the DataFrame index[0:5] is the next one= DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15'],  dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None)

Comment: I believe the issue originates from the fact that you are trying to directly access the DataFrame df with the dates in fechas as keys. However, the DataFrame index consists of more specific dates (i.e., '2019-10-15'), not just the year and the month (i.e., '2019-10').

Comment: Instead of using df[fechas[d]].copy(), you should filter the DataFrame based on the year and month. Here is how you can do it:

`filter_df = df[df.index.to_period('M') == fechas[d]].copy()`

In this line, df.index.to_period('M') transforms the DateTimeIndex to a PeriodIndex at a monthly frequency, effectively converting '2019-10-15' to '2019-10', for example. It then checks if this is equal to fechas[d], which gives a Boolean mask that can be used to filter the DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `.loc`:

```
for d in range(len(fechas)):
    filter_df = df.loc[fechas[d]].copy()  # <- HERE
    print(filter_df)
```

Output:

```
            weekday
2019-10-15        1
2019-10-15        1
2019-10-16        2
2019-10-27        6

            weekday
2019-11-24        6
2019-11-26        1
```

> Here is what I have in `fechas= ['2019-10', '2019-11', '2019-12', '2020-01', '2020-02']` and the DataFrame index[0:5] is the next one= `DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', freq=None)`

[Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
fechas = ['2019-10', '2019-11']
dti = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-10-15', '2019-10-15', '2019-10-16',
                        '2019-11-24', '2019-11-26', '2019-10-27'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'weekday': dti.weekday}, index=dti)
print(df)

# Output
            weekday
2019-10-15        1
2019-10-15        1
2019-10-16        2
2019-11-24        6
2019-11-26        1
2019-10-27        6
```